# Ищу алгоритм движения по пути

Tags: алгоритм, информатика

Задача такая: есть массив точек с координатами вида [(-0.1,0.9),(0.8,0.5)(0.4,-0.9),(-1,-0.1).....], нужно получать координату точки на линии пути от параметра T который находится в промежутке от 0 до 1, то есть 0 - начало пути (первая точка), 1 - конец (последняя точка), 0.5 середина пути, учитывая длину всех отрезков.
Особенно интересуют формулы, язык не важен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
points = [(-0.1,0.9),(0.8,0.5),(0.4,-0.9),(-1,-0.1)]
```

находишь длины отрезков между точками

```
lengths = snd $ foldl (\(sp, tl) np -> (np, distance sp np : tl)) ((0, 0), []) (tail points)
    where distance (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = sqrt $ (x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2
```

находишь длину всего пути

```
len = sum lengths
```

и т.д.

```
searchPoint t (l:ls) ((x, y):(x', y'):ps) = 
    if t <= l && t >= 0 then Just ((1-t/l)*x+(t/l)*x', (1-t/l)*y+(t/l)*y')
    else searchPoint (t - l) ls ((x', y'):ps)
searchPoint _ _ _ = Nothing
```

---

```
searchPoint (0*len) lengths points == Just (-1.0, 0.9)
searchPoint (1*len) lengths points == Just (-1.0, -0.1)
searchPoint (0.5*len) lengths points == Just (0.691, 0.121)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то Вы интересуетесь интерполяциями: [wiki Интерполяция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Тут есть ссылки на самые различные способы поиска промежуточных точек. Самая простая [линейная интерполяция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Боюсь, из тех формул не смогу ничего вытянуть, вернее сроки изучения крупноваты, хотелось бы что-то более вещественное.

Comment: Если это поможет - обычная линейная будет выглядеть таким образом:

    x_t = x_0 + (x_1 - x_0) * t;
    y_t = y_0 + (y_1 - y_0) * t;

Для каждой пары точек, и t=[0,1].

Comment: То есть остается вычислить, какая пара точек работает? А как тогда это сказывается на использовании `t`? Оно должно как-то меняться?

Comment: t изменяется от 0 до 1, т.е. при t=0.5, получим значение точки находящейся на средине отрезка между i-ой и (i+1)-ой точками.

Comment: Это если в массиве один отрезок/две точки, если больше, то при `t=0.5` искомая точка может оказаться где угодно.

Comment: Интерполяция производится между двумя соседними точками, про t выше я писал исходя из формульного смысла. Читайте матчасть.

Comment: Проще говоря, сначала находим длины всех отрезков и длину всего пути, находим в какой отрезок попадает искомая точка, потом находим координату точки по приведенной формуле. Как-то так.

Comment: так и делаю, кое что уже получается

Answer (score 0):

Для описания траектории движения по точкам могут подойти сплайны, в частности [кривые Безье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5). Хотя обычно их используют для описания гладких поверхностей.

Comment: Там нигде нет примеров для множества (>2) точек.

Comment: Кривая строится последовательно для групп точек. Например, квадратичные сплайны - это точки 0, 1, 2, затем 3, 4, 5 и так далее. Для каждых трех точек свой сплайн.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что в условии не кривая, а ломаная, так что сплайны тут ни при чем.